# Multiply two different numeric data in separate rows in react table

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose

I am trying to multiply two different data fetched from the database and have the result displayed on a table. I am having issues multiplying data from two different rows and displaying the result on same table.

```
// code to filter and render table

 renderTable() {


    var totalCount = 0;
    var shownCount = 0;
    var lowerBound = 0;
    var upperBound = 0;
    var filtered = [];

    filtered = this.state.data.map( (row, i,) => {
      if(row.department.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.departmentFilter) > -1){
        return (
          <tr key={"employeeData"+i}>
            <td>{i+1}</td>

            <td>{row.name}</td>
            <td>{row.numberofPresentAttendances}</td>
            <td>{row.department}</td>
            <td>{row.wages}</td>
            <td>{row.totalWages}</td>


            <td>


            </td>
          </tr>
        );
      } else {
        return undefined;
      }

    });
```

```
 <table className="employee-table">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>No</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Attendance in the last 7days</th>
              <th>Department</th>
              <th>Wage/hr</th>
              <th>Total Wages</th>


           <th></th>

            </tr>
            { filtered }
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

```
// mongoose models
var employeeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    department: String,
    wages:Number,
    attendances: Object
},{timestamps:true});
var Employee = mongoose.model('Employee', employeeSchema);
```

[image: output from database]

I would like to multiply the Wages/hr and numberofPresentAttendances in the frontend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question completely but if you want to show the result of (numberofPresentAttendances * wages) then you can do something like this:

```
filtered = this.state.data.map( (row, i,) => {
  if(row.department.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.departmentFilter) === -1){
    return null;
  }
  return (
      <tr key={"employeeData"+i}>
        <td>{i + 1}</td>
        <td>{row.name}</td>
        <td>{row.numberofPresentAttendances}</td>
        <td>{row.department}</td>
        <td>{row.wages}</td>
        <td>{row.numberofPresentAttendances * row.wages}</td>
      </tr>
    );
});
```

Although I am not sure why you are using variable numberofPresentAttendances instead of attendances as mentioned in your mongoose schema.